# Hidden overflow / automatic scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Sorry for the vague title. I struggled thinking about a title that would be descriptive of the problem I am facing.

I want to create a box with a limited width and a hidden overflow so that as you continue pressing buttons (digits), you see the new digits you are pressing and the digits that were pressed in the past are now hidden from view.

For example, let's say we have a box that can hold 5 digits. At first I press 1, then 3, 9, 4, and 5, showing me:

13945

If I next press 6 and 2 I would want to be shown:

94562

How do I achieve this styling given the component below? Thanks!

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      digits: 0
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event)  {
    this.setState({digits: this.state.digits + event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="digits">{this.state.digits}</div>
        <input value={this.state.digits} />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} value={1}>1</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} value={2}>2</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} value={3}>3</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} value={4}>4</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} value={5}>5</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<App />, app);
```

```css
#digits {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: that's what an input does, why not using it ?

Comment: Get the contents, remove first letter, append new letter, put it back?

Comment: you can use push() and pop() in an array to achive that

Comment: Do you care about the digits that went out of the view?

Comment: No @SujilMaharjan, I don't care about the digits that went out of view.

Comment: @Jimmy I've provided the solution below

Comment: @G-Cyr, please see the updated snipped. Input doesn't seem to solve the problem either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep all of the digits in the HTML, you could nest another container for the digits inside your `#digits` container that would not have a set width and simply float it to the right.

css:

```
#digits {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#digits div {
  float:right;
}
```

react component html:

```
<div id="digits">
  <div>{this.state.digits}</div>
</div>
```

Otherwise it might be best/reactive to push() and pop() the digits as needed, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it starts the digits off on the right hand side. I want to start the digits appearing on the left hand side. Also, this should need to work for dynamic rendering and different screen sizes, so I can't actually say for certain that there should be five digits that fill a box, etc, rather, just a certain width, whether in px or %, that the digits must fill. And once they overflow that box, to essentially automatically scroll with those new digits just like an input tag would do. I tried using an input but had some trouble, will keep trying.

Comment: You could also add `text-align:left` and a `min-width:100%` to the nested element. By automatic scrolling, are you saying that you want a user to be able to pan back and forth once the digits have overflowed the container? That won't be really be an option unless you allow an `overflow-x` on the #digits element which would reveal a scrollbar. It might be best to keep playing with styling options on an `input` element if you want that native functionality.

Comment: Thanks @user2921551, that text-align and min-width worked!

Answer (score 2):

For your solution, you need to remove the first digit before adding a new one. I am assuming that the digits variable is a string.

```
handleClick(event)  {
    // Removes the first number from the digits.
    var newDigits = this.state.digits.substr(1);
    this.setState({digits: newDigits + event.target.value });
}
```